# Create a Web Service to Send Email of daily report of database

Tags: php, database, web-services, email

I built an app in Android which updates a particular database. Now my boss tells me to built a **Web Service** that makes a day to day report of entries of each day and send it to his email id..It should work without human interaction. **I will have to just upload it to our server and it should generate a report mail on day-to-day basis** (No clicking of buttons or other stuff).

Now, I am familiarized by php and generated a piece of code (not a web service) that does generate a daily report every day. But the condition that *it should work without human interaction* is something I cant think of. For the same purpose I need to learn about Web Services ,which I dont have much knowledge about.

I have been searching on this topic since last two days and found nothing helpful. So can anyone guide me on my path, as to which material I should refer to,
as i am stuck.Thanks in advance.

Comment: See task scheduling, such as CRON - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: @DanLaManna-Yeah I searched that too..But i didnt thought it could be of any help to me...can u plz explain your answer in brief

Comment: You can schedule your PHP script in cron to run daily/hourly: 0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/report.php

Comment: @Rainer.R-But I thought that CRON is only for linux..can I use it for Windows..n I ran script every day with help of header('refresh:3600; url=my_script.php'); function...but I need to call this from somewhere..that is my actual dillema..plz reply to this..thanks for reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news:

- It's not really a Web service: see
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service
- It's actually a scheduled    task
- In php, sending email is a
  one-liner:    http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php. So the
  emailing part is    simple.  Just generate or read the report and send it
  using the mail()    function.

The scheduling part depends on the environment on your server.  On Windows, you can do it via Scheduled Tasks.  Schedule a command like this; remember to provide the correct directories etc.: php -f my-mailer.php.  You may want to wrap the command into a .bat/.cmd file.

You'll also need to make sure that your php is configured to run from command line.

To test, first run the command manually to send the report to *YOUR* email, then schedule for some short intervals.  Then change to production values.

Comment: That was excellent explanation dude. But will it satisfy the condition that I can just upload script and not trigger it manually..?? Sorry for this stupid question but m very new o this.

Comment: "There are no stupid questions; there are stupid answers." (c) No, you won't need to trigger anything manually.  Now you use php in a traditional way: called from your Web server.  The described solution is different: cron or Windows' Scheduled Tasks calls your php script via command line; the Web server is bypassed.  Totally headless; no UI.  You will need to find the Scheduled Tasks on your server (in Control Panel or elsewhere, depends on the version.)  And you may need to configure email parameters for PHP - the description on the mail function is the starting point.

Comment: You are welcome. JIC, about php email configuraion: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mail.php

Comment: ya i had that running..but only problem was with scheduler..But now its running too..